# Finds number which have same last digit from 2 different columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 columns of phone number and the requirement is to get the numbers which have same last 8 digits. ColumnA's numbers have 11 digits and columnB's numbers have 9 or 10 digits.
I tried to use **SUBSTR** or **LIKE** and **LEFT RIGHT** function to solve but the problem is the data is too big and i can't use that way.

```
select trunc(ta.timeA), ta.columnA
from table1A ta,
     tableB tb
WHERE substr(ta.columnA,-8) LIKE substr(tb.columnB,-8)
  and trunc(ta.timeA) = trunc(ta.timeB)
  AND trunc(ta.timeA) >= TO_DATE('01/01/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
  AND trunc(ta.timeA) < TO_DATE('01/01/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') + 1
GROUP BY ta.columnA, trunc(ta.timeA)
```

Comment: Please dont spam tag all RDBMS. Please specify the actual RDBMS you are using.

Comment: Are you using MySQL, MS SQL Server or Oracle?

Comment: Oracle <> SQL Server <> MySQL. This clearly is't SQL Server, as `trunc` and `TO_DATE` are not valid functions in T-SQL. Please do not tag irrelevant RDBMS.

Comment: Which SQL server technology are you using? Surely not 3 different ones?

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no aggregate functions are involved? Are you trying to do SELECT DISTINCT?

Comment: im using SQL developer but i can use mysql too

Comment: This query wont run on both MySQL and Oracle. You have to choose.

Comment: SQL developer are `IDE`.. Not `RDBMS`.. Tell what `RDBMS` you are using

Comment: What data type are columnA and columnB? You treat them like strings, but you say they contain numbers.

Comment: You only select columns from tableA. Is this on purpose? It would seem natural to show both columnA and columnB. Is it that you only want to select rows from tableA that have a match in tableB? That would rather be done with `WHERE EXISTS` instead of a join.

Comment: My rdbms is oracle

Comment: So what is the actual problem with your query? Are you saying it is correct, but becomes too slow with your big tables?

Comment: i just need column A so all i want to get is column A.

Comment: Why do the last eight digits have a special meaning for you? It sounds like you should store them in a separate column, if they have a meaning apart from the number as a whole.

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner : My problem is the query's too slow and i just want to find a fastest way to get results. the phone number was changed from 11 numbers to 10 numbers and they asked me to get back the old number from the new data which was before october 15th but didnt change anything

Comment: Again: which datatype? I suppose it's a string type, because phone numbers can contain strings (e.g. '+49401234567' or '+45-33-1234-123')? And in your system the last eight digits/letters of a telephone number have a special meaning? That is strange. How come? Are you maybe dealing with local numbers only consisting of exactly eight digit telephone numbers plus an area code of one, two, or three digits? Please explain how the numbers are formatted exactly.

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner: yes it's a string type and was filtered all the + prefix. the last time the prefix was 012x and now its 07x, and all the last 8 digits are still the same. And yeah it's only local phone number. with no symbols inside

Answer (score 1):

You want to select from tableA, so do this. Don't join. You only want to select tableA rows that have a match in tableB. So place an `EXISTS` clause in your `WHERE` clause.

```
select trunc(timea), columna
from table1a ta
where trunc(timea) >= date '2018-01-01'
  and trunc(timea) < date '2018-01-02'
  and exists
  (
    select *
    from tableb tb
    where trunc(tb.timeb) = trunc(ta.timea)
    and substr(tb.columnb, -8) = substr(ta.columna, -8)
  )
order by trunc(timea), columna;
```

In order to have this run fast, create the following indexes:

```
create idxa on tablea( trunc(timea), substr(columna, -8) );
create idxb on tableb( trunc(timeb), substr(columnb, -8) );
```

I don't see, however, why you are so eager to have this run fast. Do you want to keep all data as is and run the query again and again? There should be a better solution. Splitting the area code and number into two separate columns is the first thing that comes to mind.

**UPDATE:** Still faster than the suggested idxa should be a covering index for tableA:

```
create idxa on tablea( trunc(timea), substr(columna, -8), columna );
```

Here the DBMS can work with the index only and doesn't have to access the table. So just in case the above was still a bit too slow for you, you can try with this altered index.

And as Alex Poole has pointed out in the comments below, it should be

```
where trunc(timea) = date '2018-01-01'
```

only, if the range you are looking at is always a single day as in the example.

Comment: You don't really need to `trunc(ta.timea)` for the range comparison (I realise that's what the OP was doing, not something you added); either use the original value (so an existing index can be used, and `idxa` then isn't needed), or as it's comparing with a single day keep the trunc but it only needs to be equal to that one fixed date?

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner: Thank you sir

Comment: @Alex Poole: Yes, I could have switched from `trunc(ta.timea)` to `ta.timea` for the range, but that would have been slower, as I want the DBMS to use the function index that I have suggested. You are right that this should be a mere `trunc(ta.timea) = date '2018-01-01'` when the range in question is always a single day as in the example. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: Fair enough, I was thinking `idxa` wasn't needed, and assuming an existing index on just the raw date; but particularly with your modification then it does makes sense. Seeing trunc like that just makes me twitchy *8-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try below using `= operator` instead of `like operator`

as your want to match last 2 digit

```
select trunc(ta.timeA),ta.columnA 
from table1A ta inner join tableB tb 
on substr(ta.columnA,-8) = substr(tb.columnB,-8)
and trunc(ta.timeA) = trunc(ta.timeB)
AND trunc(ta.timeA) >= TO_DATE('01/01/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
AND trunc(ta.timeA) < TO_DATE('01/01/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') + 1 
GROUP BY ta.columnA, trunc(ta.timeA)
```

Comment: @TuanAnhTran You should change your database design such that the columns you need to compare can be used directly, without using costly string operations.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to help if you were more specific about your SQL environment, below is some advice on this query that would apply in most environments.

When dealing with large data sets performance becomes even more critical and small changes in technique can have a big impact.

For example: 
Like is normally used for a partial match with wildcards, do you not mean equals?  Like is slower than equals, if you're not using wildcards I recommend looking for equality.

Also, you initially start with a (cross/cartesian product) join, but then your where clause defines very specific match criteria (matching time fields), if you need a matching time field make it part of the table join, this will reduce the number of join results which will significantly shrink the dataset that then needs to have the other criteria applied to it.

Also, having date calculated values in your where clause is slow.  It is better to set a @fromDate and @toDate parameter before the query, then use these in the where clause as what are then literals which then don't need to be calculated for every row.